# How to use the SonarQube scanner, when using an old SonarQube version?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

Am using SonarQube 5.1.2 and Java Version 1.7.45. The SonarQube scanner 3.0.3 is only compatible with Java 8 and SonarQube v5.6.

How to analyse my code, using SonarQube 5.1.2 with the scanner? How to get a scanner for SonarQube 5.1.2?

Answer (score 3):

The [official sonar scanner documentation page](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner) is a confluence page, with a "[page history](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpreviousversions.action?pageId=6954796)" (click on `...` at the right top of the page).

When going back in history, I found out, that the version of [June, 2nd 2017](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6963052&navigatingVersions=true) refers to `SonarQube Scanner 2.6.1 – Compatible with SonarQube 4.5.4+ (LTS)`.

The **[download link](https://sonarsource.bintray.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-2.6.1.zip)** of that page is still valid, you can download the old scanner there.

But btw: I strongly recommend to update. SonarQube 5.1 is no longer maintained and later SonarQube version have a lot of improvements!